# Перебор всех значений select'ов в форме для формирования всех значений

Tags: javascript, html, form, select

Помогите пожалуйста мне перебрать и сформировать все возможные значения данных select
А именно формирование должно быть **слево -> направо**
Пример правильного формирования:

- gayka
- bolt
- sterjen
- gayka-bolt
- gayka-bolt-sterjen
- bolt-sterjen
- gayka-sterjen

То есть может быть решение только в последовательности **слева направо**, ну или может быть отсутствовать какое либо значение. Вопрос как правильно программно в цикле перебрать все доступные значения согласно примера выше. Просто когда это три селекта, можно вручную, когда их 30 голова уже кипит :(

```js
function searchHeader() { 
        var url = ""
        var gayka = document.getElementById("gayka").options[document.getElementById("gayka").selectedIndex].value;
        var bolt = document.getElementById("bolt").options[document.getElementById("bolt").selectedIndex].value;
        var sterjen = document.getElementById("sterjen").options[document.getElementById("sterjen").selectedIndex].value;
        
        if(document.getElementById("gayka").selectedIndex)
        url+= "gayka-" + document.getElementById("gayka").options[document.getElementById("gayka").selectedIndex].value + "-";
        if(document.getElementById("bolt").selectedIndex)
        url+= "bolt-" + document.getElementById("bolt").options[document.getElementById("bolt").selectedIndex].value + "-";
        if(document.getElementById("sterjen").selectedIndex)
        url+= "sterjen-" + document.getElementById("sterjen").options[document.getElementById("sterjen").selectedIndex].value + "-";
        document.getElementById("t").innerHTML += "https://google.com/" + "zapros/" + url.slice(0,-1)+"<br />";
        return false;
               
}
```

```html
<form name="form_search" action="https://google.com/search.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return searchHeader();">
<select name="gayka" id="gayka">
<option value="">EMPTY</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>


<select name="bolt" id="bolt">
<option value="">EMPTY</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="D">D</option>
<option value="E">E</option>
<option value="F">F</option>
</select>



<select name="sterjen" id="sterjen">
<option value="">EMPTY</option>
<option value="0da01">0da01</option>
<option value="zxc">zxc</option>
<option value="3dfhre">3dfhre</option>
<option value="4wer">4wer</option>
<option value="ewrew5">ewrew5</option>
<option value="6erwr">6erwr</option>
</select>
<hr />
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="GO!">
</form>
<span id="t"></span>
```

Comment: Необходимо именно список всевозможных комбинаций value в данных select'ах Вот точь в точь что мы делаем по кнопочке GO! Только сделать перебор у всех значений

Comment: Я бы не согласился, что когда 3 селекта, можно нормально все варианты написать руками. У меня вот получилось 343. 343 варианта руками написать? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я создал функцию `generateAllCombinations`, которая предназначена для создания всех возможных комбинаций значений из разных  элементов

Функция `generateAllCombinations` принимает три параметра:

- `selectOptions`: Массив объектов, представляющих  элементы и их опции
- `currentIndex`: Текущий индекс элемента  в массиве `selectOptions``
- `currentCombination`: Текущая комбинация значений

1. Функция начинает с базового случая рекурсии: если `currentIndex` равен `selectOptions.length`, это означает, что она прошла все селекты и завершает выполнение, возвращая текущую комбинацию в виде массива с одним элементом
2. В противном случае функция берет текущий селект (на основе `currentIndex`) и перебирает его опции. Для каждой опции, если её значение не пустое (не является пустой строкой), функция создает строку, представляющую выбор этой опции, в формате "имя_селекта-значение_опции". Затем эта строка объединяется с текущей комбинацией, разделенной символом "-"
3. Затем функция вызывает саму себя рекурсивно для следующего селекта (`currentIndex + 1`) и передает новую комбинацию в аргументе. Это позволяет создать комбинации для всех оставшихся селектов.
4. Кроме того, функция вызывает саму себя еще раз, но на этот раз без учета текущего селекта, чтобы создать комбинации, в которых данный селект не участвует. Это обеспечивает создание комбинаций, в которых текущий селект исключается из выбора.
5. Наконец, функция возвращает массив всех сгенерированных комбинаций, включая исключения и включения текущего селекта.

```js
const formNode = document.querySelector('form[name=form_search]');
const selectOptions = getSelectOptions(formNode);
const tNode = document.querySelector('#t');

formNode.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  searchHeader();
});

function searchHeader() {
  const rightUrl = selectOptions.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!curr.selectNode.selectedIndex) return acc;
    acc.push(`${curr.selectNode.name}-${curr.getActiveOptionNode().value}`);
    return acc;
  }, []).join('-');
  
  // tNode.innerHTML += `https://google.com/zapros/${rightUrl}<br>`;
  const allCombinations = generateAllCombinations(selectOptions);

  tNode.innerHTML = `
    Количество комбинаций: ${allCombinations.length}<br>
    ${allCombinations.join('<br>')}
  `;
}

function getSelectOptions(node) {
  const selectNodes = Array.from(node.querySelectorAll('select'));
  
  const selectOptions = selectNodes.reduce((acc, selectNode) => {
    acc.push({
      selectNode: selectNode,
      optionNodes: Array.from(selectNode.querySelectorAll('option')),
      getActiveOptionNode: () => selectNode.options[selectNode.selectedIndex]
    });

    return acc;
  }, []);
 
 return selectOptions;
}

function generateAllCombinations(selectOptions, currentIndex = 0, currentCombination = '') {
  if (currentIndex === selectOptions.length) {
    return [currentCombination];
  }

  const currentSelectOption = selectOptions[currentIndex];
  const options = currentSelectOption.optionNodes;

  const combinations = [];

  for (const option of options) {
    const optionValue = option.value;

    if (optionValue !== '') {
      const optionName = currentSelectOption.selectNode.name;
      const valueCombination = `${optionName}-${optionValue}`;
      const newCombination = currentCombination
        ? `${currentCombination}-${valueCombination}`
        : valueCombination;

      const subCombinations = generateAllCombinations(selectOptions, currentIndex + 1, newCombination);
      combinations.push(...subCombinations);
    }
  }

  const subCombinationsWithoutCurrent = generateAllCombinations(selectOptions, currentIndex + 1, currentCombination);
  combinations.push(...subCombinationsWithoutCurrent);

  return combinations;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button, select, input {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<form name="form_search" action="https://google.com/search.php" method="GET">
  <select name="gayka" id="gayka">
    <option value="">EMPTY</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>


  <select name="bolt" id="bolt">
    <option value="">EMPTY</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
  </select>



  <select name="sterjen" id="sterjen">
    <option value="">EMPTY</option>
    <option value="0da01">0da01</option>
    <option value="zxc">zxc</option>
    <option value="3dfhre">3dfhre</option>
    <option value="4wer">4wer</option>
    <option value="ewrew5">ewrew5</option>
    <option value="6erwr">6erwr</option>
  </select>
  <hr />
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="GO!">
</form>
<span id="t"></span>
```

Comment: Да но получается что Вы сделали рефакторинг кода, но сколько вариантов комбинаций option в select все также неизвестно :((((

Comment: Это прекрасное решение, которое несомненно я благодаря Вам буду использовать в дальнейшем, но я наверно не правильно выразил свои мысли. Первоначальная задача в которой я запутался, это автоматический перебор всех option. То есть то что мы сейчас делаем по кнопочке GO! Вот мне нужны все варианты option которые могут быть. Извините за неправильное объяснение требуемой задачи

Comment: У вас нет вариантов только с болтами или только со стержнями и их комбинациями без гайки

Comment: Очень красивое решение, но как заметил @EzioMercer действительно не все варианты учтены.

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Спасибо все отлично! Сейчас тестирую! Вы гений!

Comment: Теперь всё есть :)